# How to add file to .gitignore with \n in the filename

Tags: linux, git, gitignore

I just want to add file with `file
name` (file name contains \n) to .gitignore.

I try:

```
/file
name

/file\nname

file\
name
```

but have no luck.

Comment: Files with newlines embedded in their names are pretty evil. :-) Git is supposed to handle them correctly though, and in this case, there's no perfect answer for .gitignore entries.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/file*name
```

`*` should match any characters.

Comment: but in this case files with names like fileXname will be ignored too

Comment: Either `*` or you have to rename the file. There is no way to insert a filename with newlines into a line-oriented text file (`.gitignore`).

Answer (score -1):

Please tell me this is a homework assignment.

The .gitignore file uses a glob(7) style wildcard substitution so embedding a '*' should work.  Linux really doesn't care about the filename spelling, so *any* character other than a '/' can go into a filename.  On a command line be sure to use single-quotes (not double-quotes, mind you) so the shell doesn't get confused.

Reading the filenames from ls(1) and similar will split the name at the \n character because the glibc standard library is looking for newlines to find the end of a line of text.  The '/' and '\n' characters are treated specially in many levels of the software stack, like the pathname of the file or splitting a buffer into lines or displaying the filename or letting awk(1), sed(1), and such scan a list of filenames.

But I agree with another poster: this is a bad idea.  No, I take that back, it's a horrible idea.  Long-term maintainability is going to be a nightmare.